# Seekbar - Add image equally distibuted with points

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to achieve similar UI as shown in the image. I have the points equally distributed but how to add image below that equally distributed. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWfo8.png)

*github.com/woxingxiao/BubbleSeekBar*

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5s2w.png)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.xw.repo.BubbleSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/bubbleSeekBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:bsb_auto_adjust_section_mark="true"
                    app:bsb_bubble_color="@color/colorVitalRed"
                    app:bsb_bubble_text_color="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:bsb_max="10"
                    app:bsb_min="0"
                    app:bsb_progress="0"
                    app:bsb_second_track_color="@color/blue"
                    app:bsb_section_count="10"
                    app:bsb_section_text_position="below_section_mark"
                    app:bsb_show_progress_in_float="false"
                    app:bsb_show_section_mark="true"
                    app:bsb_show_section_text="true"
                    app:bsb_show_thumb_text="false"
                    app:bsb_track_color="@color/colorWhite" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pain_0_emoticon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pain_0_emoticon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pain_0_emoticon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pain_0_emoticon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pain_0_emoticon" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you can do is use custom seek bar and arrange image using **Linear layout**.it will look the same as design.

Comment: @Jaymin , I tried but it will vary as i want images below 0, 2, 4, etc .. equal intervals

Comment: did you try using **layout_weight**?

Comment: @Jaymin yes..not perfect. Is there a way we can use images with seekbar ?

Comment: Can you post you xml along with images ?

Comment: @Jaymin updated

Answer (score 1):

**Check this out**

[Result](https://postimg.org/image/ueaj6g36h/)

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<com.xw.repo.BubbleSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/bubbleSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:bsb_auto_adjust_section_mark="true"
    app:bsb_bubble_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:bsb_bubble_text_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:bsb_max="10"
    app:bsb_min="0"
    app:bsb_progress="0"
    app:bsb_second_track_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:bsb_section_count="10"
    app:bsb_section_text_position="below_section_mark"
    app:bsb_show_progress_in_float="false"
    app:bsb_show_section_mark="true"
    app:bsb_show_section_text="true"
    app:bsb_show_thumb_text="false"
    app:bsb_track_color="@color/colorAccent"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note :**
**Please change your image resources with my image and also color resources**